# Perl. Есть ли изящный способ валидации utf-8?

Tags: perl, utf-8, io

Задача проверить документ на корректность. Читать буферами определённого размера, потому-что данные не доверенные( вдруг там нету символов конца строки ). Раз мы читаем буферами из-за этого возможны битые символы utf-8. Значит нужно читать символами указав соответствующую кодировку, при открытии файла. Далее нужно проверить на валидность utf-8 и в случае ошибки вывести смещение битого символа в файле. Как это изящно реализовать? Такой мощный язык и всё через какие-то диковатые костыли.

Comment: а если бы это был не перл, могли бы реализовать изящно?

Comment: Да уж perl. Они оболочку со стандартными утилитами не смогли заменить. По теме. Попробуй использовать утилиту iconv. Она показывает смещение недопустимых последовательностей. Этот язык не для серьёзных вещей. Code Golf да пожалуйста. Посмотри какой у меня однострочник тоже сгодится. Но не для серьёзных вещей.

Comment: Ухаха господа вы серьёзно? Рассмотрим [пример](https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html#FB_QUIET) из документации. Сразу несколько вопросов. А у буфера ведь нету ограничений и куча сломанных символов легко сожрут память? А если несколько кусков символов раскиданы по файлу и из них соберётся символ который будет валидный? И ни слова об этом. Зато куча пафосных тру программистов. Вот поэтому никто не пишет на этом языке. В оправдание перлу только одно, они всё таки пытаются описать возможные ситуации, в отличии от других.

Answer (score 0):

```
open( my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file ) or die $!;

while( read($fh, $buf, $size) ) {
    # Изящно и логично было бы здесь,
    # перехватывать исключения слоя.
    # В этом случае читаются целые символы
    # и есть возможность отслеживать реально битые.     
}
```

Но увы это невозможно. Вместо этого надо городить какие-то подпорки...